# How to use Oracle database as Masstransit SagaStateMachine persistence?

Tags: masstransit, state-machine, saga

```
`services.AddMassTransit(x =\>
{
    x.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();

    x.SetEntityFrameworkSagaRepositoryProvider(r =>
    {
        r.ExistingDbContext<RequestSagaDbContext>();
        r.UseSqlServer();
    });
}`
```

There isn't r.UseOracle. How to use oracle instead of sql server?

I try to install Oracle.Entityframework but doesn't solve the problem.